# Type '{ className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Any ideas why I am getting the error here? Any ide how should I enter the className?

**"Type '{ className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322"**

here is the code:

```
type Props = {data: {
pin?: boolean;
category: string;};}

export default function Icon({ data: { pin, category } }: Props) {
  const icon = {
    All: <All  />,
    "UX Researcher": <UxResearcher />,
    "UI/UX Designer": <UiuxDesigner className={`icon icon-${category}`} />,
```

Answer (score 0):

`UiuxDesigner` is a custom component that doesn't support the property `className`. If this is a component from a library, contact the maintainers and ask for it to be added. If this is a component you or your team made, add it as an argument and pass it down. Alternatively, you could wrap with `` <div className={`icon icon-${category}`}> ... </div> `` and see if that is enough for your desired result.